# ggplot conditionally change shape or shape fill using variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line chart that shows open symbols for data that is not detected and closed (filled) symbols to represent detected data.   Here is the some code to work with:

```
date <- c("1991-04-25","1991-04-26","1991-04-27","1991-04-28","1991-04-29","1991-04-25","1991-04-26","1991-04-27","1991-04-28","1991-04-29","1991-04-25","1991-04-26","1991-04-27","1991-04-28","1991-04-29")
Parameter <- c("TEA","TEA","TEA","TEA","TEA","COFFEE","COFFEE","COFFEE","COFFEE","COFFEE","WATER","WATER","WATER","WATER","WATER")
data <- c(5,4,7,3,6,4,6,8,6,3,7,8,7,6,7)
DetectYN <- c("Y","N","Y","Y","Y","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","Y","Y","N")

df <- data.frame(date, Parameter,data, DetectYN)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d" )
df$DetectYN <-as.character(df$DetectYN)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=data)) +
geom_point(size=4, aes(shape = Parameter , colour= Parameter)) +
geom_line(aes(x=date, y=data,color = Parameter)) +
scale_shape_manual(values=ifelse(DetectYN == "Y",c(15,16,17),c(0,1,2)) , guide = "none")
```

This creates the following chart - nearly correct, except that my ifelse is not having the desired effect.   I would like the DetectYN = "N" to be hollow (no fill) and I would like the DetectYN = "Y" to be filled. The existing symbols need to remain.  Could anyone help me with this please? [image]

Comment: Your code works for me  (I get a mix of filled and empty point symbols).  Is this a typo?   Where you have  `values=ifelse(LOC$DetectYN == "Y",c(15,16,17),c(0,1,2)) `  do you mean `values=ifelse(DetectYN == "Y",c(15,16,17),c(0,1,2))  `      No LOC$

Comment: Sorry - that was a relic from my actual code... OK I flushed my environment and was able to reproduce as you say (thank you) but this is still not quite right.   If you look at the data frame, you see that for example, Coffee, there should be two points that show non detect and and three points that show detected.   At the moment, they all show non-detect (assuming it is taking the first value in the group).  I've edited original code to take out the 'LOC' reference. @G5W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a deceptively difficult problem!
This solution directly answers your question, and is hopefully of some use. However, I fear that it may become messy with large, complicated datasets.

I added a column combining the two variables that you wish to control shape, and then defined shape by this new column, ordering the shape numbers to achieve the desired result.

```
df$shape<-paste(Parameter, DetectYN)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=data, colour= Parameter)) +
  geom_point(size=4, aes(shape=shape))+
  geom_line() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,15,1,16,2,17) , guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: A very clever solution!  Thank you!  Agreed, it may be complicated with larger data sets - but this directly helps my real life problem and should be readily implementable given your solution.